# Rewrite rule for ePages. From page to new URL

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I try to make a rewrite rule for ePages.

Example:

**Link is:** www.test.com/epages/Test.sf?ObjectPath=/Shops/Test/Categories/testCat/testPage

**New URL is:** subtest.newtest.com

My Code is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/epages/Test.sf
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ObjectPath=/Shops/Test/Categories/testCat/testPage$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subtest.newtest.com/ [R=301]
```

But after the redirect I get:

https://subtest.newtest.com/?ObjectPath=/Shops/Test/Categories/testCat/testPage

But it need to be:

https://subtest.newtest.com/

What do I have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use with below,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subtest.newtest.com/? [R=301]
```